# Anushthana of naam japa

Tags: shiva, vishnu, shakti, nama-japa

I have heard about anusthana of mantra japa.

For mantra and anusthana guru is necessary for permission and others valuable reasons.

But to get a actual guru in kaliyug is tricky.

In other hand, naam japa of deity can be done by any person (No initiation required).


Questions:

- Can anyone do anusthan of 108 shotam or 1008 shotram ?
- What are rules for that?

Scripture reference will be helpful.